# How to assure, that the record was added to the database?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, tapestry

I have two applications:

- the first one insert a record to the postgresql database (let's assume it's id equals X) and notifies the second one
- the one which was notified sends mails to the users, but before that it checks if the record with id X (it was included in the "notify message" from the first machine) was inserted into the database

In 99% cases it works well, but sometimes the second machine cannot find the record with the given id. How it is possible?

On the side of the first machine I use hibernate and save the object into the database like that:

```
objectDao.save(object);
```

And then send the message:

```
publisher.sendObjectAddedMessage(user.getId(), ipSource.getIpAddress(), object.getId());
```

Nothing fancy. I tried to flush the hibernate right away or wait a little bit before sending the message, but event then the problem occurs.

My PostgreSQL version is:

```
PostgreSQL 9.3.5 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2, 64-bit
```

Comment: If you increase the time before sending that message  it's ok ? The record appears on db  or missing ? Or registration appears in the database after sending the message?

Comment: On the side of the second machine, I implemented 'three attempts' mechanism (timeouts), which sometimes helps, but not so often.

Answer (score 1):

It's highly recommended that you call `publisher.sendObjectAddedMessage()` using some event listener.

i.e., You should create a listener that will call a method after any object is persisted, so as to ensure that your `sendObjectAddedMessage()` is by no mean called before entity was persisted.

Consider this example:

I will persist this simple entity `Person.java` and I will associate several events with this class. Whenever this entity will be saved, some methods will be called before and after the transaction responsible for this entity was committed.

Person.java

```
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue ( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
    int id;

    String name;

    //getters and setters below this
    ...
}
```

Now consider my `Main` class. You can see that I've created `AuditLogInterceptor` and have associated it with the session.

By associating this interceptor with session, it will call several methods like `onSave`, `preFlush` and `postFlush` methods of this interceptor. This will ensure that these methods are always called when required. (like `postFlush` won't be called before entity was saved)

Test.java

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AuditLogInterceptor interceptor = new AuditLogInterceptor();

        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory()
                .withOptions()
                .interceptor(interceptor)
                .openSession();
        interceptor.setSession(session);        

        Person p = new Person();
        p.setName("John Doe");

        session.getTransaction().begin();
        session.save(p);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

This is the code for main class `AuditLogInterceptor.java`. It implements `EmptyInterceptor` interface of hibernate. As you know in `Test.java`, we associated the session with this interceptor. Hence it's overridden methods will be called on several events like save, update etc...

AuditLogInterceptor.java

```
package test;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.hibernate.CallbackException;
import org.hibernate.EmptyInterceptor;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.type.Type;

public class AuditLogInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor{
    Session session;

    public void setSession(Session session) {
        this.session=session;
    }

        @Override
    public boolean onSave(Object entity,Serializable id,
        Object[] state,String[] propertyNames,Type[] types)
        throws CallbackException {

        System.out.println("onSave");

        return false;

    }

    //called before commit into database
        @Override
    public void preFlush(Iterator iterator) {
        System.out.println("preFlush");
    }   

    //called after committed into database
        @Override
    public void postFlush(Iterator iterator) {
        System.out.println("postFlush");                        
    }   
}
```

and now the Output

```
Hibernate: drop table if exists hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: drop table if exists Person
Hibernate: create table hibernate_sequence (next_val bigint)
Hibernate: insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )
Hibernate: create table Person (id integer not null, name varchar(255), primary key (id))
Feb 16, 2016 8:23:18 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000230: Schema export complete
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
onSave
preFlush
Hibernate: insert into Person (name, id) values (?, ?)
postFlush
```

As you can see we printed `onSave`, `preFlush` and `postFlush` on colsole in `AuditLogInterceptor.java`.

During the `postFlush`, you can call your `publisher.sendObjectAddedMessage()`. In my opinion, this will work correctly for 100% of all cases :)

*To know more in detail, please refer to [this](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-interceptor-example-audit-log/) example.*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to use event listeners (@PostPersist)?
E.g. http://alexandregama.org/2014/03/23/entity-listeners-and-callback-methods-jpa/

```
public class MessageListener {

    @PostPersist
    private void send(Object object) {
        //send
    }

}

    @EntityListeners(MessageListener.class)
    public class ObjectPOJO {
    }
```